# SQL command in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a problem. 
I'm trying this SqlCommand to get the fields from a Database with 2 conditions :

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Article where Domain like '%Geography%' order by Title";
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
ListView1.DataBind();
```

or like :

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Article where Domain ='Geography' order by Title";
 SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
 ListView1.DataBind();
```

but the result is I get everything from the Article table meaningless of the Domain name.

My data source is defined as

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="
<%$ ConnectionStrings:WikipediaDatabaseConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Article] ORDER BY [Title]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How are ListView1 and SqlDataSource1 connected?

Comment: Can you post your whole code of connection

Comment: does it work if you run it directly in SQL (e.g. via SSMS)? Looks like there's nothing wrong with the query. Show how your listview and Sql data source are linked. It's not clear whether one is having any impact on the other.

Comment: First off does the code run if you run directly in the SQL Management window. Second, both of your statements only show 1 condition so neither of them will return based on 2 conditions unless you use an 'AND' statement for example

Comment: As long as the query looks correct, perhaps all the rows in the Article table have Domain = 'Geography'??

Comment: No , I don't have all the domain = ' Geography'

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WikipediaDatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Article] ORDER BY [Title]"></asp:SqlDataSource>    this is from the asp.net , I think here is the problem because I don't have the where clause .

Comment: ok. so define the SelectCommand in one place - either in the aspx page or in the code-behind. Not in both, you are confusing yourself.

Comment: thanks! I did that and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running both of those queries, which are as simple as you can make a query and the results are not what you expect, there are only a small number of possibilities:

- You are not pointing at the database you think you are
- You are not not actually sending the query you think you are
- You are not correctly looking at the data and the results are correct

I really don't see how it could be anything but one of these.

Comment: Looks like #2, see the data source definition from the comments